# Convert a tab (Mapinfo) file to ESRI Shapefile with ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, convert, ogr2ogr, tab, bash

I want to convert a tab file created with MapInfo to an ESRI Shapefile (.shp) using ogr2ogr in command line.

I did the following

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' "file.shp" "file.tab"
```

but it gives an error:

```
Unable to open datasource `file.tab' with the following drivers.
```

I use gdalv2.4

Do I have to specify anything else?

Comment: did you try:  ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" file.shp file.tab
i think the problem is because you are mixing " and '. the filenames don't need to be in quotes were as the file type option -f has to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following both commands should work with double quotes `""` surrounding the file format `"ESRI Shapefile"` and with or without double quotes `""` surrounding the files names:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "file.shp" "file.tab"
```

Or

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" file.shp file.tab
```

But using single quotes `''` surrounding the file format `'ESRI Shapefile'` will raise an error:

```
Unable to open datasource `file.shp' with the following drivers (in my case).
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got this working but the easiest way is to use QGIS which is essentially a GUI for ogr2ogr. If you load in your .TAB file into QGIS you can right click in the layers panel and click

Export > Save Features As..

From here you can select a number of formats to save as.

Chris

Comment: True, but OP might be trying to run the conversion programatically.